# How do you get Google Trends to go back before 2004?

Tags: google-trends

How do you get Google Trends to go back to a year in the distant past, for instance 1900? It seems to not go back before 2004 now.

I remember using a Google feature that showed a graph of how common certain search terms were, by year, and I recall it going back quite far.

I've seen the following picture

[image: sample graph]

I guess perhaps it's from Google.

When I look for the feature, I see a thing called Google Trends, but it doesn't go back before 2004.

So it's not clear to me whether the thing I'm looking for is another Google service (perhaps discontinued by Google?), or if Google have crippled their Trends service. Or if there's some fiddly thing in their new GUI, that I'm not aware of, that makes it possible to go back before 2004.

Regarding any answer, if it's to tell me that Google Trends doesn't, then I'd like to know what service it was that did. I think it was a Google service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are perhaps conflating the functionality of Google Trends with the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams).  It's possible that they were connected together at some point, but the two are definitely separate products now.

Comment: yeah I think I was conflating them. Worth adding to your answer that google trends can't go back before 2004 as stated by wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Trends

Comment: Just add that Trends center on "searches" on the web, while ngram centered in "aparissions" in books; which is not the same. While the first centered attention on what "people" is interested in, second one centered attention on what is published on books, papers, news, among others.